# High GPU usage on Dell e7450 - power

Tags: windows-10, gpu, dell-latitude

I use the pc normally.

Pc starts to be very very slow.

I look at task manager and I see high GPU usage

[image]

Look at the process:

[image]

Then I look at Intel(R) Extreme Tuning Utility: note that "power limit throttling" is enabled

[image]

Now I unplug my power cable from the laptop and this happens. The "power limit throttling" is disabled.

[image]

Now I look at task manager

[image]

I put PC to sleep and start again. Now works fast.

[image]

"power limit throttling" is still enabled but pc is fast. I'm not sure what is the problem.

Normally my pc runs very hot (on the left side) and no much cpu is used (30%). I don't know why everything seems to take a lot of CPU, like small things.

Also not sure why is so hot all the time. I reinstalled windows and still hot, even on idle.

Anyway looks like there is a bug and once it enters in this power limit, it will not come back to the normal state without restart.

Any solutions? I have an i7 5600, I think is good enough for browsing without getting hot, but is hot.

(Bottom airways are not blocked)

Answer (score 1):

Driving the GPU continuously at almost 100% capacity will heat it up,
and depending on the case, may also heat the hardware around it.
Most modern CPUs will slow down when the temperature is too high,
and some will not return to normal performance without reboot.
This seems to be your case.

However, it is not normal for the GPU to run that way.
If this is a program of yours that does it, you should put some limits
on its use.

If it is not your program, check that the Client Server Runtime Process
is running from the system : In Task Manager right-click it and select
"Open file location".
Explorer should open to the `C:\Windows\System32` directory where the program
is called `csrss.exe`.
You may get more detailed information by using
[Process Explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer).
If it is not the right one, then your computer is infected
and is probably busily mining crypto-currency.

If you are infected, you should deep-scan your computer with several well-known
anti-virus products and see if they find anything.
For more information see the post
[How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, adware, viruses, trojans or rootkits from my PC?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit).

Comment: I think the problem is that my pc is getting hot, will power limit GPU, then all tasks will take 100% of my GPU, because the GPU is limited to its 10% (or similar, I made this number up) of original power. Its a fresh windows installation so I doubt is malware, maybe windows update.

Comment: Windows Update shouldn't use the GPU, it uses normally the Internet and RAM and a little CPU.

Comment: I mean, maybe windows updated messed up my system

Comment: That's always a possibility and it does happen a lot, but I think other avenues need to be explored first, because 100% GPU is not a normal symptom for such problems. If you wish to go this way, it starts with the relatively benign but heavy [In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html), but the only step after that would be a fresh install. Ensure you have excellent backups before starting.

Comment: 100% gpu happens because the gpu is limited by intel, check the screenshots.

Comment: @Totty.js: Intel is the CPU, it's the motherboard that has the heat sensors and controls the fans. The motherboard usually has better control on the CPU than the GPU. You should take care of the two problems : Excessive use of the CPU+GPU plus improving the cooling.

Comment: I'm not using "CPU+GPU", just normal webdevelopment (file watchers) and browsers. GPU looks to be used by Windows to show the actual square windows. Not sure how to improve cooling in my laptop, but that looks like another kind of problem. The thing is this behaviour was not happening before, my pc could handle this tasks without power throttling. "Intel Dynamic Platform and Thermal Framework" is the reason of the power limit, and from reading online looks like has some buggy behaviour. Limits when the temperature of the pc is 80 degrees c. I don't know how to fix it...

Comment: There are products such as [ThrottleStop](https://www.techpowerup.com/download/techpowerup-throttlestop/), but you should only use them if you are sure the heat readings are off.

Comment: I don't know, the heat is around ~80. To use that looks like I need to disable intel thermal framework but I couldn't find any proper instructions (except a long documentation +200 pages but can't find what I need), do you know any? (the software is not selfexplanatory)

Comment: 80 C is OK, no need to worry, so there's no need for throttling. A harmless trick to reduce temperatures is in Control Panel -> Power Options > Change plan settings > Change advanced power settings > Processor power management > Maximum processor state, set to less than 100%. Even 2-3% less will have an effect.